# Expect script to Check file type and changing it before running script

Tags: linux, unix, expect

I am attempting to write a script to run a script, but before I run the script I want to check if it is dos or unix format and convert it accordingly. Here is what I have so far:

```
spawn ssh root@login
expect "assword:"
send "myPass\r"
expect "#"
send "cd /myDir\r"
expect "#"

if head -1 *.sh | grep $'[\x0D]' >/dev/null  #check to see if dos or unix
   then   #if dos then convert to unix and change permissions
    dos2unix *.sh
    chmod 777 *.sh
   else   #else execute script
    ./*.sh
fi

expect "#"
```

Am I allowed to include if statement in the middle of the expect script like this? Also how can I execute multiple command after the if statement( the dos2unix and chmod).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using conditional statements inside 'expect'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538444/using-conditional-statements-inside-expect)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't mix shell and expect like that, but you can send a complex shell command:

```
send "cd /myDir\r"
expect "#"
send {for f in *.sh; do head -1 "$f" | grep -q $'[\x0D]' && { dos2unix "$f"; chmod 777 "$f"; }; ./"$f"; done}
send "\r"
expect "#"
```

Comment: Could you explain the for loop line please, how does the if statement translate to the for loop?