# Expect script conditional scenario

Tags: expect

I am trying to use the expect utility to automate a task which requires inputting the password during script execution.

```
expect -c "set timeout 120; 
spawn /bin/bash /home/user/script.sh; 

# Expect 1 - not expected always
expect \"Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?\"; send "yes\r"; 

# Expect 2 - not expected always
expect \"Please type 'yes' or 'no':\"; send \"yes\r\"; 

# Expect 3 - this is required always to input the password
expect \"user@xyz.com's password:\"; send \"password\r\"; expect eof"
```

From the script above, expect 1 and 2 conditions are not required always. Its only needed when executing the script against new servers. Once the identity of the host is added to known hosts, the first 2 expect conditions wont be prompted by the script. Expect 3 is the only condition to be met in most of the cases.

In a system, where the host identity already exist, the expect script executes the first condition and stays until the timeout is reached and doesn't get to expect 3. I am not sure how to achieve this, but is there a way in expect to break if a prompt is not met.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1538444/1005215

Comment: expect is not part of bash, it's not specific to bash, it's not shipped with bash, it doesn't even utilize bash under-the-hood (the language it's based on is TCL). You could run an expect script without having bash installed at all. The bash tag has no place in a question specific to expect.

Comment: thanks, the expect command itself is not  bash as per the script. script.sh which i want expect to execute is a bash script however which is why i am calling the bash executable

Answer (score 3):

The `expect` command has a time out, which I forgot how long, but just a couple of seconds. If not found what you are expecting, time out occurs and the expect command will exit. With that in mind, I have set the timeout to 1 second and seems to work. You might want to adjust it to your system.

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
package require Expect

spawn /bin/bash /home/user/script.sh 

# Time out (in seconds) for the expect commands
set timeout 1

expect "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? " { send "yes\r" }
expect "Please type 'yes' or 'no':" { send "yes\r" }
expect "user@xyz.com's password:" { send "password\r" }
interact
```

A couple of notes:

1. This script is not a bash script. It is a TCL script with Expect package. I recommend doing thing this way as TCL is very capable, yet not too hard to learn.
2. The `timeout` value is the the key here. You might even want to set different time-out values before each `expect` command to tailor your script's response time.
3. Setting `timeout` to 120 is too long: Each `expect` command will have to wait 2 minutes before moving on, at which time, your system might timed out before you can get to the next `expect` command.

Good luck.

Comment: /home/user/script.sh takes about 60 secs to execute, worst case i wanted expect script to fail, if it goes beyond 120 secs.